# Template embedding in gwt application

Tags: html, css, gwt

I have template with its css and html.Now I want to get all the look 
and features (compatibility) of that template in my gwt application. 
I am not getting the right way to do that. 
One way which I thought is that for control there will be a .html 
file , which will be added to the gwt root panel using frame.I also 
don't know it is right way or not. 
Please help me out to embed all the look and feature of the template 
to the gwt application.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use your html template as the GWT [host page](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideHostPage).

The tricky part is using GWT Widgets. GWT Widgets, especially layout panels, produce their own html, which might not match your template and/or css.

You might get around that somewhat by wrapping Widgets around existing html by using `widget.wrap(element)` method. This method is available on some widgets: Label, TextBox, etc..

Also, if your css is class-oriented, you might get by by setting proper style classes of widgets: `widget.setStyleName(className)`.